# How to iterate over a built variable using string interpolation Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON file that contains a sample data

```
{
  {
  "AL": {
    "type": [
      [
        { "option": "some text" },
        { "yes": { "url": "" } },
        { "no": { "url": "" } }
      ],
      [
        { "option": "some text 1" },
        { "yes": { "url": "" } },
        { "no": { "url": "" } }
      ],
      [
        { "option": "some text 2" },
        { "yes": { "url": "" } },
        { "no": { "url": "" } }
      ],
      [
        { "option": "some text 3" },
        { "yes": { "url": "" } },
        { "no": { "url": "" } }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
  "AK": {
    "type": [
      [
        { "option": "some text 4" },
        { "yes": { "url": "" } },
        { "no": { "url": "" } }
      ],
      [
        { "option": "some text 5" },
        { "yes": { "url": "" } },
        { "no": { "url": "" } }
      ],
      [
        { "option": "some text 6" },
        { "yes": { "url": "" } },
        { "no": { "url": "" } }
      ],
      [
        { "option": "some text 7" },
        { "yes": { "url": "" } },
        { "no": { "url": "" } }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I get the data using jQuery's getJSON method

```
var response;

var data = $.getJSON("data/data1.json", function(data) {
    return data;
  });

  data.then(function(res) {
    response = res;
  })
```

I am trying to construct a variable that maps to the attributes in this Object.

I have tried the like

```
var key = "response[" + $dropdownKey + "]" + ".type";
```

and also

```
var key = "response." + $dropdownKey + ".type";
```

Where $dropdownKey is set when I select using a `<select></select>` tag in my HTML.

With this I want to iterate over the Object and get the data;

```
key.map(function(value) {
  I'd like to get all the options then
})
```

Because I have many attributes in the Object, I wanted to be able to dynamically tell this `map` function that the location of the attributes change based on user selection.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `key` is a string? Response doesnt exist when you get it? `providerType` is not `type` ?

Comment: Where is providerType?

Comment: you cant map over a string. do you just want the data specific to the state code from the select menu? cant you just do keyData = jsonData[key]

Comment: My mistake, i meant to have type and not providerType. I have updated my code

Comment: This question might be best served by some reading. I suggest [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086) and [Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6393943)

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

1) You try to turn something asynchronous (the data will arrive somewhen) into something synchronous (the data is there):

```
  data.then(function(res) {
    response = res;
  });
```

that won't work in most of the cases. Instead you should work with the promises as they are meant to, don't try to pass data out the promise chain.

2) your `key` is a string. You don't want a string. If you remove the `"` it is actually working.

---

```
  const data = $.getJSON("data/data1.json");

  function onSelect(dropdownKey) {
     data.then(response => {
       response[dropdownKey].type.map(type => {
         //...
       });
    });
  }
```