# Deleting from an object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object as shown:

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'FolderA',
    child: [
      {
        name: 'FolderB',
        child: [
          {
            name: 'FolderC0',
            child: [],
          },
          {
            name: 'FolderC1',
            child: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'FolderM',
    child: [],
  },
];
```

And I have path as string:

```
var path = "0-0-1".
```

I have to delete the object:

```
{
    name: 'FolderC1',
    child: [],
 },
```

Which I can do so by doing,

```
arr[0].child[0].splice(1, 1);
```

But I want to do it dynamically. Since path string can be anything, I want the above '.' operator and splice definition to be created dynamically to splice at particular place.

Comment: Have a look at [Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into a reference to the object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6393943/1048572)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could reduce the indices by saving the last index and returning the children of the actual index. Later splice with the last index.

```js
function deepSplice(array, path) {
    var indices = path.split('-'),
        last = indices.pop();

    indices
        .reduce((a, i) => a[i].child, array)
        .splice(last, 1);
}

const array = [{ name: 'FolderA', child: [{ name: 'FolderB', child: [{ name: 'FolderC0', child: [] }, { name: 'FolderC1', child: [] }] }] }, { name: 'FolderM', child: [] }];

deepSplice(array, "0-0-1");
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could split your `path` and use the parts, like so:

```
let path = '0-0-1';
let parts = path.split('-');

// Call your splice using your parts (unsure if your '1' is the index, or deleteCount).

// If parts[2] is the index
arr[parts[0]].child[parts[1]].splice(parts[2], 1);

// If parts[2] is the deleteCount:
arr[parts[0]].child[parts[1]].splice(1, parts[2]);
```

Comment: This I want to be dynamic, I don't know how long the path nested would be:  arr[parts[0]].child[parts[1]].splice(1, parts[2]);

Comment: Does your string of `0-0-1` change in length / depth?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a recursive function which travels down the hierarchy till the path is available. Below is a very minimal snippet.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'FolderA',
    child: [
      {
        name: 'FolderB',
        child: [
          {
            name: 'FolderC0',
            child: [],
          },
          {
            name: 'FolderC1',
            child: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'FolderM',
    child: [],
  },
];

let ar_path = "0-0-1";

function deleteRecursive(arr, path) {
  if(Array.isArray(arr) && path.length > 0){
     const index = Number(path.shift());
     if (path.length > 0) 
        deleteRecursive(arr[index].child, path)
     else 
        arr.slice(index, 1);
  } else {
     console.log('invalid');
  }
}


deleteRecursive(arr, ar_path.split('-'))

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the path is always going to be composed by 3 (or less) indices you can do it easily like the following:

```js
function deleteByPath(arr, path) {
   const index = path.split('-').map((x) => +x);
   if ( index.length < 1) {
      return null;
   } else if ( 1 === index.length ) {
     return arr.splice(index[0], 1);
   } else if ( 2 === index.length ) {
     return arr[index[0]].child.splice(index[1], 1);
   } else {
     return arr[index[0]].child[index[1]].child.splice(index[2], 1);
   }
}

const arr = [
  {
    name: 'FolderA',
    child: [
      {
        name: 'FolderB',
        child: [
          {
            name: 'FolderC0',
            child: [],
          },
          {
            name: 'FolderC1',
            child: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'FolderM',
    child: [],
  },
];

console.log(deleteByPath(arr, "0-0-1"));
console.log(deleteByPath(arr, "0-1"));
console.log(deleteByPath(arr, "0"));
```

If the path is going to be composed of maybe less than 3 parts you can adjust the function `deleteByPath` to handle cases based on number of parts.

if the path is going to be arbitrary and can have any length you can adjust the `deleteByPath` function to be recursive like the following:

```
function deleteByIndexRecursive(arr, index, current) {
  return current+1 < index.length ? deleteByIndexRecursive(arr.child[index[current]], current+1) : arr.child.splice(index[current], 1); 
}
function deleteByPath(arr, path) {
   const index = path.split('-').map((x) => +x);
   if ( 1>index.length) {
     return null;
   } else if ( 1===index.length) {
     return arr.splice(index[0], 1);
   } else {
     return deleteByIndexRecursive(arr[index[0]], index, 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: No, path can be of any length :)

Comment: @MichaelPhilips, updated answer to handle path of 1,2 or 3 parts. You can add more cases as needed by example

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Variable setup:
const arr = [
    {
        name: 'FolderA',
        child: [
            {
                name: 'FolderB',
                child: [
                    {
                        name: 'FolderC0',
                        child: [],
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'FolderC1',
                        child: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'FolderM',
        child: [],
    },
];
const path = "0-0-1";
//Break the path into pieces to iterate through:
const pathArray = path.split("-");
//Javascript assignments are by reference, so arrayToManage is going to be an internal piece within the original array
let arrayToManage = arr;
//We are going to iterate through the children of the array till we get above where we want to remove
while(pathArray.length > 1){
    const key = parseInt(pathArray.shift());
    arrayToManage = arrayToManage[key].child;
}
//Get the last position of the last array, where we want to remove the item
const key = parseInt(pathArray.shift());
arrayToManage.splice(key,1);
//And because it's all by reference, changed we made to arrayToManage were actually made on the arr object
console.log("end result:", JSON.stringify(arr));
```