# How to access property of nested object given dynamic keys?

Tags: javascript

I have a nested object of which I do not know the structure of. For example:

```
const nestedObject = {
  "one": {
    "two": {
       "three": 3
     }
  }
}
```

I wanted to display value of `three`.

I have an array like this so that I know how to navigate the object in order to get to `three`:

```
const keys = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

This doesn't have to be structured this way.

So how do I access `one.two.three` given the `keys` array above? Or some other data structure. I was thinking of doing a recursion, but it seems too complex and I feel like there is a simple solution out there.

Comment: Please post the JavaScript in a [mcve]. If you haven't actually tried anything yet...do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with a simple [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```js
const data = {
  "one": {
    "two": {
       "three": 3
     }
  }
};

const keys = ["one", "two", "three"];

const value = keys.reduce((a, v) => a[v], data);

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MyObject["fieldName"]` to access the sub object. And then, you can use a recursive function that will use the array containing the indexes to roam through the object

```js
let MyObj = {
  "one": {
    "two": {
       "three": 3
     }
  }
};

let Keys = ["one", "two", "three"];

function getValue(obj, arrIndexes, index = 0)
{
  let currentIndex = arrIndexes[index];
  let currentObject = obj[currentIndex];
  
  if (index < arrIndexes.length - 1)
  {
    return getValue(currentObject, arrIndexes, index + 1)
  }
  else
  {
    return currentObject;
  }
}

console.log(getValue(MyObj, Keys));
```