# convert string with dot notation to object

Tags: javascript

I having issues understanding the proper way to convert a string like so `tree.descendents[0].descendents`
to a object that I can manipulate. 
I was seeing that reduce was the way to go, however I couldn't wrap my head around it.
Any suggestions/pointers appreciated.

```
class TreeNode {
constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.descendents = [];
}}
```

As you can see I might be deep within the tree object. I am trying to access it by getting the path to my target then set its value.
ideally I convert the path to a object and do: myPath.descendents.push(myNewElement)

Comment: What type of object should a string like `tree.descendents[0].descendent` be? I feel like there's some context missing. Do you have a an object like `const tree = { descendents: [ . . . ] }`?

Comment: Please tells us what reference you are using for "the proper way to convert a string like so `tree.descendents[0].descendents` to a [sic] object".

Comment: I have a tree object that within itself has descendents and those descendents have there own descendents.

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference?