# Turn array to a deep level of object

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array and a sample object like this:

```
const array = ['a', 'b.c', 'c.d.e']
```

Sample

```
const sample = {
  'aa': 'test',
  'a': 'value',
  'b': {
    'c': 'value'
  },
  'c': {
    'd': {
      'e': 'value'
    }
  },
  'e': {
    'f': {
      'g': {
        'h' : 'value'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I want to make a new object basing on the sample. The result should look like this:

```
const newSample = {
  'aa': 'test',
  'a': 'oldvalue' + 1,
  'b': {
    'c': 'oldvalue' + 1
  },
  'c': {
    'd': {
      'e': 'oldvalue' + 1
    }
  },
  'e': {
    'f': {
      'g': {
        'h' : 'oldvalue'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm thinking of loop through the array and count the length of each element. However, it's not as efficient as the level of the array and sample increase. Are there any algorithms that can be done better?

```js
const array = ['a', 'b.c', 'c.d.e']

const sample = {
  'aa': test,
  'a': 'value',
  'b': {
    'c': 'value'
  },
  'c': {
    'd': {
      'e': 'value'
    }
  },
  'e': {
    'f': {
      'g': {
        'h' : 'value'
      }
    }
  }
}

const newSample = {}

const transformer = (array) => {
  array.forEach(item => {
    const itemArr = item.split('.')
    if (itemArr.length === 1) {
      console.log(sample[itemArr[0]])
      newSample[itemArr[0]] = sample[itemArr[0]] + 1
    }
    // the condition goes on...
  })
}
transformer(array)
console.log(newSample)
```

Thanks,

Comment: The only difference I can see between your `sample` and desired result is that some `value`s have changed to `someValue` but it's not clear where that comes from. The structure looks the same — it's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: why is `a` not nested? and so on?

Comment: Where the `value/someValue` comes from ?

Comment: Sorry. The question is updated. The new value is calculated from the old value.

Comment: do you want a new object or mutating the old one?

Comment: @NinaScholz I want a new one. The answers below look good. I need time to check both of them unless you have a better solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to apply a new value to a set of scoped-fields.

You could just loop over your desired scoped-fields and set a new value for them. The answer to the following question: [Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference) works very well for this problem set.

#### Warnings

If you need to deep-copy or clone the object, you can serialize-deserialize it:

```js
function cloneObject(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Normal assignment does **NOT** handle deep-copies:

```js
function cloneObject(obj) {
  return Object.assign({}, obj);
}
```

```js
const array = ['a', 'b.c', 'c.d.e', 'e.f.g.h'];

const sample = {
  'a': 'value',
  'b': {
    'c': 'value'
  },
  'c': {
    'd': {
      'e': 'value'
    }
  },
  'e': {
    'f': {
      'g': {
        'h': 'value'
      }
    }
  }
};

const newSample = setValueForKeys(cloneObject(sample), array, 'someValue');

console.log('Updated:', newSample);
console.log('Original:', sample);

function setValueForKeys(source, keys, value) {
  keys.forEach((key) => index(source, key, value));
  return source;
}

function cloneObject(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

// See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394168/1762224
function index(obj, is, value) {
  if (typeof is == 'string') return index(obj, is.split('.'), value);
  else if (is.length == 1 && value !== undefined) return obj[is[0]] = value;
  else if (is.length == 0) return obj;
  else return index(obj[is[0]], is.slice(1), value);
}
function multiIndex(obj, is) {
  return is.length ? multiIndex(obj[is[0]], is.slice(1)) : obj;
}
function pathIndex(obj, is) {
  return multiIndex(obj, is.split('.'))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This solution is really good. However, it also mutates the original object :(

Comment: @DaleNguyen Added cloning and notes.

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the splitted keys and save the last key for the assignment with the last key.

```js
const 
    keys = ['a', 'b.c', 'c.d.e']
    object = { a: 'value', b: { c: 'value' }, c: { d: { e: 'value' } }, e: { f: { g: { h : 'value' } } } },
    transformer = (objec, keys) => keys.reduce((r, s) => {
        var path = s.split('.'),
            last = path.pop(),
            final = path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, r);

        final[last] = (final[last] || '') + 1; // or whatever you need change
        return r;
    }, object); 

console.log(transformer(object, keys));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Nonmutating approach by returning a deep copy with changed value.

```js
function transformer(object, keys) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        r[k] = v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? transformer(v, keys.filter(s => s.startsWith(k + '.')).map(s => s.split('.').slice(1).join('.')))
            : keys.includes(k) ? (v || '') + 1: v;
        return r;
    }, {});
}


const 
    keys = ['a', 'b.c', 'c.d.e']
    object = { a: 'value', b: { c: 'value' }, c: { d: { e: 'value' } }, e: { f: { g: { h : 'value' } } } }; 

console.log(transformer(object, keys));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This solution is really good. However, it also mutates the original object :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `forEach` loop to loop each element in the array and then `split` each path to array and then use `reduce` method on that path array to update each nested property.

```js
const array = ['a', 'b.c', 'c.d.e']
const sample = {"a":"value","b":{"c":"value"},"c":{"d":{"e":"value"}},"e":{"f":{"g":{"h":"value"}}}}


function update(array, sample) {
  array.forEach(c => {
    c.split('.').reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
      if (!a[i + 1]) r[e] = r[e] + 1
      else return r[e] || {}
    }, sample)
  })
}

update(array, sample);
console.log(sample)
```

Comment: This solution is really good. However, it also mutates the original object :(