# Get data from object passed from html with pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I want to get data from the object like this

```
const translate = {home:title:'Home'}}
```

we use `home.title`, and this is ok.

But I need to change this `home.title` to `[home][title]`

I need this, because, I made pipe, and with this pipe, I send value from HTML view like

```
{{ "home.title" | getTranslate}}
```

and I need to take value from the array, let's say `arr[home.title]` but this not working, I need this `arr[home][title]`.

EDITED:

I convert a value from HTML to format as I want

```
let b = value.split(".");
let keyTranslate = "[" + b[0] + "]" + "" + "[" + b[1] + "]";
console.log(keyTranslate)    // [home][title]
```

And now I pass this value to another function

```
this.store.select(fromStore.TranslateSelector.translateKey(keyTranslate ));
```

And here I want to take value by this key

```
export const translateKey = (key: any) => createSelector(
    getTranslate, 
    translate => console.log(translate[key]));  // this not working.
```

How to set "key" to translate array?

Comment: `arr` is not an array currently, it's an object with a property that's also an object. `arr[x][y]` is only used in 2d arrays. But you can access properties using the keys as strings, as `arr["home"]["title"]`. Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: i edited my question, pls take a look

Comment: looks like you may want to look into transloco though :) https://github.com/ngneat/transloco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found soution if someone else stuck with this, with ECMAscript 6 it is easy

```
key.split(".").reduce((o, i) => o[i], translate)); --> // translate.home.title
```

Here is full explanation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394168/7167775