# Testing conditions on a constantly changing object in javascript

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I'm trying to create a browser game. The game state is stored in an object with multiple layers.

```
let State = {
    points: 0,
    health: 50,
    currentLocation: {x: 5, y: 55},
    inventory: { bread: 8, water: 33, money: 20 }
    abilities:
        charisma:5,
        perseverance: 3,
        speed: 8
    }
    buildings {
        bakery: { location: {x: 23, y: 41}, unlocked: 1, visited: 1},
        homestead: { location: {x: 3, y: 59}, unlocked: 0, visited: 0},
        forge: { location: {x: 56, y: 11}, unlocked: 1, visited: 0}
    }
    
}
```

I want to be able to control the game logic based on the current values of State.

Some cases are very simple
`if(State.health == 0) { Game.die(); }`

Most cases are much more complex

```
if(State.buildings.bakery.unlocked == 1) {

    // calculate player's distance to bakery
    let dX = Math.abs(State.buildings.bakery.location.x - State.currentLocation.x)
    let dY = Math.abs(State.buildings.bakery.location.y - State.currentLocation.y)
    let d = DX + dY;
    
    if(State.inventory.bread == 0 && d < State.inventory.abilities.speed) {
        Game.die();
    }
    
}
```

What is the best way to achieve something like this? Looping over all the conditions seems to be a needless use of resources. I've looked into getters, setters and Proxy but don't really know what I'm doing! Ideally I'd only want to only check the logic when a relevant part of State changes.

Comment: Both getters/setters or Proxy would be the way to go. If you have a problem with such implementation, please reduce your example to just the one property you have a problem with, and include your implementation, and where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd only want to only check the logic when a relevant part of State changes.

Then use a `getter` and `setter` like this:

```js
let State = {
  buildings: {
    bakery: {
      _unlocked: false,
      get unlocked() {
        return this._unlocked;
      },
      set unlocked(value) {
        this._unlocked = value;
        if (value == true) {
          console.log("Calculating player's distance to bakery ...");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

State.buildings.bakery.unlocked = true;
// Calculating player's distance to bakery ...
```

The use of the `_unlocked` variable is because if you didn't, the first time `unlocked` is accessed, it will trigger its own getter recursively until you get a stack overflow error.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.

To know `if(State.buildings.bakery.value1 + State.buildings.forge.value2 > 50)` I'd have to call it from both setters. I want to put my conditions in a single location in the code

`let State = {
  buildings: {
    bakery: {
      _value1: 10,
      get value1() {
        return this._value1;
      },
      set value1(value) {
        this._value1 = value;
      }
    },
 forge: {
      _value2: 20,
      get value2() {
        return this._value2;
      },
      set value2(value) {
        this._value2 = value;
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Yes, you will need to check the condition inside the getters of both `value1` and `value2`.  Write the check as a single function, then call the check function inside both getters, so that you only have to define the condition check once.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've ended up doing...

```
const state = {

    _data:{}, // object in which the data is actually stored

    get:(path) => { // safely get the value or return undefined 
        return path.split('.').reduce((o,i)=>(o||{})[i], state._data)
    },
    
    set:(fullpath,value,silent=0) => { // safely set the value
        
        function cycle(obj,path,value) {
            let i = path[0]
            
            if(path.length==1) { // if this is the end of the path
                obj[i] = value; // change the value
                if(!silent) { Pubsub.publish('state.'+fullpath, value) ; } // and publish the event
            } else { // if this is not the end of the the path
                if(typeof obj[i] !== 'object') { obj[i] = {} } // create this part of the path if it doesn't exist
                cycle(obj[i],path.slice(1), value) // move on to the next part of the path
            }
        }
        
        cycle(state._data,fullpath.split('.'),value)
            

    }
```

### Step 1: Get and set

I created two custom functions to get and set the state.

get() takes a dot notation path as a string, e.g. `state.get('buildings.bakery.unlocked')`.

set() also takes a dot notation path as a string as well as the value, e.g. `state.set('buildings.bakery.unlocked', 1)`.

I used some code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference). Using these functions means it's easy to manipulate nested properties without worrying about the dreaded TypeError.

### Step 2: PubSub

The dot notation path also feeds a publish/subscribe model. I'm using [PubSubJS](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS). Calling set() also publishes an event that matches the path, e.g. `state.set('abilities.strength', 5)` also publishes `'state.abilities.strength'`.

To monitor state changes, you simply subscribe to the relevant events:

```
PubSub.subscribe('state.abilities.strength', () => console.log('strength value changed'))
```

The published event also passes back the new value, so you can do what you want with it:

```
PubSub.subscribe('state.inventory.bread', (path, value) => console.log('bread value changed, you now have ' + value))
```

### Step 3: Implement to compare

PubSub has the benefit of being a topic based system. This means you can subscribe to non-final nodes:

```
PubSub.subscribe('state.inventory', () => console.log('something in the inventory changed'))
PubSub.subscribe('state.inventory.water', () => console.log('water changed'))
```

Changing `inventory.bread` will trigger the first, changing `inventory.water` will trigger both.

This allows me to separates the game logic from the state. There's two ways to compare values...

```
    // function to compare two values
    let comparison = function () {

        console.log('running comparison');

        if(state.get('test.valueA') > state.get('test.valueB')) {
            console.log('A is bigger than B');
        }
    }

    // you either subscribe to both the values, and compare whenever either one changes
    PubSub.subscribe('state.test.valueA', comparison)
    PubSub.subscribe('state.test.valueB', comparison)
    
    // or alternatively, if they have a shared topic, then subscribe to that
    PubSub.subscribe('state.test', comparison)
```