# How to update a Vuex child key with Object.assign?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When `payload.key` is a key like `foo`, the code below is working fine, but how to update the value of a child key like `foo.bar.a` ?

```
export const mutations = {
  USER_UPDATE(state, payload) {
    console.log(payload);
    state.user = Object.assign({}, state.user, {
      [payload.key]: payload.value
    });
  }
}
```

#### === EDIT ===

This is called by:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(['user']),
  fooBarA: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.state.user.foo.bar.a
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.commit('USER_UPDATE', {
        key: 'foo.bar.a',
        value
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the whole `state.user` Object reference with a new Object, which destroys reactivity.

This simplified code does not demonstrate the need to use `Object.assign`, so in this cas you can simply:

```js
export const mutations = {
  USER_UPDATE(state, payload) {
    state.user[payload.key] = payload.value
  }
}
```

Which keeps the original `state.user` Object reference.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. However, `payload.key` is creating a variable like this `state.user['foo.bar.a']`, while I need `state.user.foo.bar.a`, any way to convert this string into children keys ?

Comment: Not a trivial task, but here's a very good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference . This does not exactly do what you want, but should point in the right direction.

Comment: What I want to add here: I use `vuex` with primitives and arrays only to avoid problems like this. It's easier said than done, I know. But if you're able to create `user` as a `vuex.module` and thus, flatten it to primitives, all of this is resolved. Probably a tedious task, but for me it was always worth it.

Comment: The post you sent discourage to do things the way I'm doing it. Is there maybe something I can change in the way I'm calling the mutation ? (I have updated my post to show how the mutation is called).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think there's no _nice_ way to do this :-/ It is best practice to avoid complex structures in `vuex` mainly for this reason. You probably have to flatten your data structure and add mutators for all of `user`s mutatable data. Here again, I give you the hint to use `vuex` modules, which somewhat allowes nested Objects, but you have to add all the mutators anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I just deleted my answer... the problem came from my Vuex tool not recording the changes.

Comment: So I deleted mine :p

Answer (score 1):

I have an approach that works.

Where the `payload.key` is `"foo.bar.a"`

```js
const mutations = {
  UPDATE_USER(state, payload) {
    const setter = new Function(
      "obj",
      "newval",
      "obj." + payload.key + " = newval;"
    );
    let user = { ...state.user };
    setter(user, payload.value);
    state.user = user;
  }
};
```

Demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-nested-key-setter-x1n00

Inspiration from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30360979/815507

Comment: Nice to avoid using lodash !