# Retrieve nested value from nested typescript type using dotted string

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to retrieve / update a nested value in a custom Typescript type using a dotted string?

```
interface IChild {
  childName: string;
}

interface IRoot {
  root: string;
  child: IChild;
}

const O:IRoot = {
  root: "Root name",
  child: {
    childName: "Child Name"
  }
}

console.log(O['child.childname']); // Not allowed
```

Is there a way of accessing this prop using dotted notation?

Edit: I have put this together to show how I am getting the value using dot notation from a nested type

```
    type Prev = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...0[]];

    type Join<K, P> = K extends string | number ?
        P extends string | number ?
            `${K}${"" extends P ? "" : "."}${P}`
            : never : never;

    type NestedKeyof<T, D extends number = 10> = [D] extends [never] ? never : T extends object ?
        { [K in keyof T]-?: K extends string | number ?
            `${K}` | Join<K, NestedKeyof<T[K], Prev[D]>>
            : never
        }[keyof T] : ""
        
    const state: IRoot = {
        name: "Root",
        child: {
            childname: "Child1",
            grandchild: {
                childname: "Child2"
            }
        }
    } as IRoot;

    const getProperty = <P extends keyof T, T>(o:T, p:P ) => {
        return o[p];
    }

    const getNestedProperty = <P extends NestedKeyof<T,3>, T>(o:T, p:P ): any => {
        const parts = String(p).split(".");
        let temp: any = getProperty(o, parts[0] as keyof T);
        parts.shift();
        parts.map(p=> {
            temp = getProperty(temp, p as keyof typeof temp);
        })
        return temp;
    }
    
    console.log(getNestedProperty(state, "child.grandchild.childname"));
```

The magic seems to be that when you have an anonymous type you can type guard using

`keyof typeof anonymoustype`

So as you recurse the structure you can use this to satisfy typescript.

Comment: Either `O.child.childName` or `O['child'].childName` or `O['child']['childName']` or `O.child['childName']`

Comment: Alas I think in any case example 2,3 and 4 will not work with Typescript but also none of these are dotted notation strings which was my question.

Comment: No. This is Typescript.

Comment: Have a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394168/18716297

Comment: How come `ts` and `js` differ in accessing objects , JS + Types = TS, The link I provided holds true for JS and TS.

Answer (score -1):

First thing, it won't be allowed. The property name is "childName" and you're accessing it as "childname". ( casing issue )

Second, you can access any property using dot notation in ts. Even your IDE will typehint it for you.

Here, check I have just copy pasted your code on this online Playground for TS and changed the console log to dot notation only.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGEAWwA2ATZAbwChlkFt8A5OAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5iBfY4qEixEKVACUA9pLBFSyKNLBNW7EN3kVceJhkp4e-YgkkhWyAPIMJS5AF45ZRTKYAiKTOQg6EVwBpNfSYSMjItah83LG1kGnpXeX4jEzNJHAgAOhxJDgAKCwzwvEL9OIgASi4gA

Comment: Hey Hesan, that's good. I want to do the same but with the dot notation as a sting literal.