# Calling a namespaced callback function by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably basic...  given a fully qualified function name, I'm trying to call it via `.apply()`

Superficial example

```
var ns = {
    someFunc: function() { console.log('stuff'); }
}

function someTopLevelFunc() { console.log('top level'); }
```

Given a method that takes the name of that function, us there some way to call the namespaced function?

```js
function theCaller(funcName) {
  console.log("Callback name: " + callbackFunctionName)
  const callbackFunction = window[callbackFunctionName];
  console.log("Type: " + (typeof callbackFunction))

  if((typeof callbackFunction) === "function") {
     callbackFunction.apply(null, []);
  }
}

theCaller('topLevelFunc');
theCaller('ns.someFunc');
```

The first call works while the second call shows the `callbackFunction` type as `undefined`

Probably a simple syntax issue, but my googling has failed me.

Comment: Why do you need these dynamic function names to begin with? Use a single object and access the property name like this: `const ns = { someFunc(){} }; const funcName = "someFunc"; ns[funcName]();`.

Comment: This may be a pedantic nitpick, but the function is a method of the `ns` object. I'm not sure "namespaced" is the best way to think about it

Comment: This is a superficial example. In the real case, the calling function is not in the same application.  Trying to provide a generic ability to callback a named function in any namespace.  Or are you suggesting to pass a reference to the function instead of the name?

Comment: Perhaps calling is "namespaced" is wrong...  I agree.  I'm still interested in if possible (and how) to call a nested function in an object given its fully qualified reference name.  Whatever the best way to describe it is

Comment: Does this question provide you with an answer? [Convert a JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394168/2181514)

Comment: In JavaScript, if you want to call a function, you either have to directly obtain a reference to this function, or the name of the property holding the function paired with the object that has the property. You normally don’t use a string like `"ns.someFunc"`. What specifically do you mean by _“the calling function is not in the same application”_? If you can’t get an object reference, then at least have one fixed object that holds all functions as properties and refer to the function you need by key name.

Comment: The question linked by freedomn-m is likely a sufficient answer.  To Sebastion Simon, "theCaller" is completely unaware of the "ns" object in this case.  It's a generic JavaScript library which provides some processing, and can callback a given function after processing completes.  In this case we have a handful of grails applications and this javascript is provided by a plugin.  The plugin needs to call a JavaScript function defined in the parent application given the name.

Comment: @freedomn-m if you'd like to post that link as an answer I'll mark this resolved.