# Handlebars like parser in React

Tags: reactjs, handlebars.js

I am trying to build a generic parser so the variable value I am getting is a name of an object, example:

```
let foo = "user.id";
```

and then I want to replace foo with user's id. How do I go about that? (obviously thinking of eval but eval is evil :) )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-a-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference)